# your device is not compatible with this version

Tags: java, android, sdk

app is not compatible with many devices minimum sdk version is 16 and thats my permissions in the app

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true" />


<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />
```

Gradle
  minSdkVersion 16
  targetsdkversion 28

Comment: What is your question? Please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: camera2 supports sdk>=21

Comment: but it should work for sdk greater than 21 it's not work for any device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to used

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"  />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

this permissions required at least minimum sdk version is 19. So try to update it by using

> minSdkVersion 19

in build.gradle file

Comment: but it should work for sdk greater than 19 it's not work for any device